# Overloading operator compile error?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

So I'm trying to overload the ^ operator to perform the intersection between my two sets, but I keep getting this compile time error "Invalid operands to binary expression.

intersection = list ^ listTwo; is what causes the error

My methods work fine without overloading.

Here is my header file.

```
#ifndef SetHeader_h
#define SetHeader_h

template<typename T>
class Node{

     public:
     T data;
     Node<T> *next;

};

template<typename T>
class SetADT{

private:
     Node<T> *head;

public:
     SetADT();
     ~SetADT();
     void add(T data);
     void print();
     bool isDuplicate(T data) const;
     SetADT<T> operator ^ (SetADT<T> node);

};


#endif /* SetHeader_h */
```

Here is my cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SetHeader.h"
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
SetADT<T> ::SetADT(){
    head = NULL;
}
template<typename T>
SetADT<T> :: ~SetADT<T>(){

    cout<<"Set deleted!" << endl;
}

 template<typename T>
 bool SetADT<T>::isDuplicate(T data) const{

    Node<T> *cur = this->head;

      while (cur) {
         if (cur->data == data) {
           return true;
      }
        cur=cur->next;
     }
   return false;
 }


    template <typename T>
    void SetADT<T>:: add(T data){

    Node<T> *node = new Node<T>();

    bool isPresent = isDuplicate(data);

    if (!isPresent) {
        node->data = data;
        node->next = this->head;
        this->head = node;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void SetADT<T>:: print(){

    Node<T> *head = this->head;

    if (head == NULL) {
        cout << "{}";
    }

    Node<T> *cur = head;

    while (cur) {
        cout << cur->data << ' ';
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}


template <typename T>
SetADT<T> SetADT<T> :: operator &(SetADT<T> one){
    SetADT<T> result;

    Node<T> *setACurrent = this->head;

    while (setACurrent) {
        if (one.isDuplicate(setACurrent->data)) {
            result.add(setACurrent->data);
        }

        setACurrent = setACurrent->next;

    }
    return result;
}


int main (){


    SetADT<int> list;
    list.add(10);
    list.print();

    SetADT<int> listTwo;
    listTwo.add(10);
    list.print();

    SetADT<int> intersection;

     //error right here
    intersection = list ^ listTwo;


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You are trying to use `^` on two pointers. This is not possible. Actually what you should do is use it on two `SetADT<T>` objects.  Operator overloading overloads operators for class-type objects, not pointers. Also you defined your `operator^` to work with a `SetADT<T>` on the left and a pointer on the right. This is a bad idea.  It would greatly improve your code to stop using any pointers to `SetADT<T>`.

Comment: @M.M that should be the answer imho

Comment: @M.M so I changed the pointers to class-type objects, and I get invalid operands to binary expression.

Comment: You made a mistake somewhere...

Comment: @M.M I posted my new code can you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: The code you have now doesn't have any compilation errors for `operator^`  - although there is one for `operator&` (you have a definition but not a declaration for that).   But to avoid runtime errors you will also need to give `SetADT` a move-constructor, and you should pass by const-reference into the operator functions (not pass by value). Look up "rule of five" on cppreference.com

Comment: The move-constructor could look like: `SetADT(SetADT<T>&& other) { head = other.head; other.head = nullptr; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essence of your problem is that the operator function is defined for the class `SetADT<T>`, however you are are trying to invoke the ^ operator against pointers (to objects); the compiler does not match your operator function implementation to your usage. Only the bitwise-xor (`^`) operator is defined and it does not know how to handle `SetADT<T>` arguments.

In order for the complier to match the invocation with your declaration, you need to dereference the left-hand "argument," `list`.

```
intersection = *list ^ listTwo;
```

I might suggest that you write the operator to accept reference arguments rather than pointers, like so:

```
SetADT<T>* operator ^ (SetADT<T> &node) { … }
```

Then you invoke it,

```
intersection = *list ^ *listTwo;
```

Of course you can leave the existing declaration/definition in place if there is a reason for it, but it is not *nice*. You should consider returning a reference to the object rather than a pointer. And, for completeness, you should consider implementing the `^=` operator, as well.

```
SetADT<T>& operator ^ (SetADT<T> &node);
SetADT<T>& operator ^=(const X& rhs);
```

Then the expression to use for `^` operator could look like,

```
*intersection = *list ^ *listTwo;
```

Comment: Thank you! I changed it to SetADT<T>& operator ^ (SetADT<T> &node); and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for this quickie, I am rejuvenating my C++ skills after a long time in java...and this was what I required exactly

Answer (score 0):

```
list ^ listTwo;
```

Both `list` and `listTwo` are a `SetADT<int> *`, a pointer to an instance of this template. Both operands of this `^` operator are **pointers**.

```
template<typename T>
class SetADT{

// ...
     SetADT<T>* operator ^ (SetADT<T> *node);
```

Here you defined the `^` operator of a `SetADT<T>`, and ***not*** a `SetADT<T> *`.

This `operator^` declaration ends up overloading an operator *on an instance of the class*, and ***not*** on a pointer to the instance of the class.

That's how `operator` members work: they overload an operator on an instance of the class, and not on a pointer to an instance of the class.

If you would like to invoke this operator correctly, the right syntax would be:

```
(*list) ^ listTwo
```

Here, `*list` dereferences a pointer to an instance of a class, so you end up with (a reference to) an instance of the class, which has an `operator^` overload that takes a pointer to an instance of the same class as a parameter.

Note that your `operator` overload's parameter is a pointer to an instance of the class, and since `listTwo` is such a pointer, this should work.

The general mistake you are making is that you are not correctly understanding the fundamental difference between a class and a pointer to an instance of the class. The is not a trivial matter, it's an important distinction. If something is defined to work for an instance of a class, it expects to have an instance of a class to work with, and not a pointer of such a class. And vice-versa.

Comment: Good answer up until the last bit - overloaded operators must have at least one operand a class type , there is no way to overload an operator for two pointers, or two integers for example, etc.  Your code won't compile

Comment: I tried to do it as a friend function and that did not work.

Comment: Ok, removed that last bit, then.